# How to specify the input method action for input text fields in an Android's WebView

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, cordova-plugins, android-keypad

I'm creating a hybrid android application and was wondering within a webview, how do you specify the html input text box to control what type of keyboard that pops up.  Specifically, how to trigger either the "GO" or then "next" error in the native keyboard that pops up when you focus on an input text box.

I searched the web, but only found references when working with native android code https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html.

However, i'm not seeing how the webview communicates with android to distinguish what type of keyboard to display from just the html.  I'm wondering is there specific html tags that trigger certain formats.

My use case is when you have a text input box, the keyboard pops up with a "next"  button.  The problem is that when the user presses the "next" button it doesn't hide the keyboard.  It needs to be the "Go" button or "Done" button.

Let's say in my example I have one input field that is used for search.  It's not part of a form, but does have a search button next to it that is hooked up onclick.

Example:

```
<div>
    <input type="text">
    <div id="searchIcon"></div>
</div>
```

There are actions in javascript that help bind it to the input text field.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks
D

Comment: Does your input is in a form ?

Comment: How many input fields do you have ? and are they in form ?

Comment: With multiple inputs, If you have set required on the input fields, then next will be shown.

Comment: updated the post, but no the input is not in a form.  There is only one input field and the field is not set to required.